# Overriding x86 SS segment for PUSH and POP instructions (SS:SP, SS:ESP, SS:RSP)

Tags: assembly, x86, callstack

I need to interpret/emulate the PUSH and POP family of x86 instructions.

**My current question by now is:**

Can PUSH and POP instructions accept segment override prefixes such that I can push or pop to `ES:SP`, `CS:SP`, `DS:SP`, `FS:SP` or `GS:SP` instead of  **`SS:SP`**?

Comment: What's wrong with the CPU documentation?

Comment: I think the segment overrides only apply to "the memory operand", e.g., for *push address*, it would only apply to the *address* part, not what push does with the contents of address.  I agree that Alexey that you should consult the CPU docs; they are generally extremely clear on what instructions do.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I think there's nothing wrong with the Intel/AMD manuals. It may just be that I have made so many painful mistakes in the past requiring full rewrites of programs (which took weeks or much more time to write) due to accumulation of tiny/subtle bugs, that now I'm extremely cautious about implementing ideas, and I need to verify if what I am understanding is accurate, from the knowledge of a whole community. And with the highly technical nature of the manuals (requiring not just the CPU manuals), I now know I would be delusional to think I wouldn't be fatally wrong at some point.

Comment: The manuals require very little else: practice. You read about something, then you try it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segment override prefix affects location of source for PUSH and location of destination for POP.
You can't override segment of stack.